# Can't iterate over two arrays while using salt-ssh

Tags: arrays, bash

I am trying to use two arrays in a salt-ssh command but it appears to be ignoring the files array as it responds with "cannot remove '/test/': Is a directory".

So it appears to not even see the *files* array.

```
servers=("server1" "server2" "server3" "server4")
files=("test1" "test2" "test3" "test4")

for i in ${!servers[@]}; do
   salt-ssh ${servers[i]} -r 'rm  /test/${files[i]}'
done
```

If I add double quote around the salt-ssh command it reads it correctly, yet tells me the file doesn't exist (verified it does exist on the server).

```
salt-ssh ${servers[i]} -r "'rm  /test/${files[i]}'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolve the issue by replacing single quote with double quote only as...

```
salt-ssh ${servers[i]} -r "rm  /test/${files[i]}"
```